# Best way to use currency converter for faster result

Tags: php, performance, api, currency, codeigniter-3

Currency i am using google finance api for converting currencies the code is below

```
 <?php
      function convertCurrency($amount, $from, $to){
        $url  = "https://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=$amount&from=$from&to=$to";
        $data = file_get_contents($url);
        preg_match("/<span class=bld>(.*)<\/span>/",$data, $converted);
        $converted = preg_replace("/[^0-9.]/", "", $converted[1]);
        return round($converted, 3);
      }

      # Call function  
      echo convertCurrency(1, "USD", "INR");
      ?>
```

everything is working fine i am getting the correct conversion but now the problem i am facing is that on my website lot of products gonna be there so i have to use foreach for iterating through all the products and while iterating through the loop i am calling the currency converter function to convert the price based on user location but as the product is increasing so the time it tooks to convert all currency is also increasing.So just wanna know is there any other way through which i can do this conversion so that it don't effect the performance of my site.

Comment: Interesting: "[The Google Finance APIs are no longer available. Thank you for your interest](https://developers.google.com/finance/)". I was going to see if they have rate limits in place; your website isn't the only one affected by so many requests…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all as a starting point do not try convert all the price every time. You just need a conversion rate so one api call per page load.
let's assume you are converting the price from USD to GNF (I am from Guinea) .
just convert from 1 USD -> ? GNF

```
$UsdToGnfRate=convertCurrency(1, 'USD', 'GNF')
```

from now on you can use this rate to convert all your product prices from USD to GNF by multipliying the product price by the rate you got from the api

```
foreach($products as $item){
  $localPrice=$item['price'] * $UsdToGnfRate
}
```

You can make some test and see for your self or look for currency conversion which is based on the rate. This way you don't call the api for every product on your page.

Comment: its really a good solution but not applicable in my case..my requirement is little bit different.Actually in my web app a user can post a product from anywhere based on his country currency but the user who is seeing that product shld see the currency based on his location..For example if a user post a offer from US then he will post in USD and from Guinea he will post in GNF but as i am an Indian so i am gonna see that price in INR so this function gonna change for every offer from  convertCurrency(1, 'USD', 'INR')  to convertCurrency(1, 'GNF', 'INR')..IN short from currency keep on changing

Comment: If that is the case then I would suggest to get the conversion rate for all currencies and put them in a  php array  that way it will be more convenient. Here is what I will do:  create a conversion rate table that i will update every 6 hours using the google api & a cron job. Whenever the page load just pull the coversion rates in a php array to work with.. conversion rate changes a lot but for my experience 6 hours is a great balance.

Comment: Thanks mate by using your method and some additional tweak i was able to implement that functionality.Thanks alot